# Stormpath React SPA user login

Tags: nginx, reactjs, stormpath

I'm developing a React app using webpack and intend to serve my app using nginx. Reading through the Stormpath examples I'm confused if I can develop a client side SPA since all the examples I've found use express to serve the application. I think it might be possible to keep my app running using the webpack dev server but will need to use the Stormpath rest API's rather than the React libraries.

I initially thought I would have server side code that would connect to Stormpath and my client code would connect to my server but I just can't find a example that shows this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

For SPA applications, you can instruct our Express library to only respond to JSON requests, this esesntialy tells it to only expose the JSON API:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  web: {
    produces: ['application/json']
  }
}));
```

Then you can use a different mechanism, such as nginx,  to serve the assets for your SPA.  This information is in the [Single Page Applications](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/configuration.html#single-page-applications) section of the [Express-Stormpath documentation](http://docs.stormpath.com/nodejs/express/latest/).  I work at [Stormpath](https://stormpath.com) and I'm more than happy to help!  You can also get support through support@stormpath.com.

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert. Can you please clarify the topography?

nginx: 80 - serving static html

nodejs, express, stormfront:3000 - express rest API ?

client app - POST/ GET to nodejs:3000

I'm not sure what I do on the client side. Should I use the same React stormfront components in the examples? 

e.g. login, where should I send the user name / password from the client login screen?

Comment: The documentation for the express-stormpath library has information about the JSON endpoints and the type of information it expects, each section has information about the JSON format.  As long as your nginx server is forwarding requests to your express application, everything should work without concern.